# Passing data to another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, parameter-passing, master-detail

I am using the Master/Detail template. I have a TableView that will pass data (text) to one of two labels on the Detail view controller. In the Detail view controller I have two buttons. Depending on which button is selected I want the data from the table view will be displayed in the associated label.

When I have filled one label and want to select the second label the data in the previous label is cleared and only the second label is filled with text.

I guess that when the segue executes and the view did load is called the Detail view is cleared of data from the prior selection.

I want the prior data to remain in the prior label when another is selected.

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Can you please share some code so we can get a better sense of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @implementation SecondViewController

int mainSubSelect = 100;

- (IBAction)mainButton:(id)sender {
    mainSubSelect = 100;
    
}
- (IBAction)subButton:(id)sender {
    mainSubSelect = 200;
    
}

-(void)configureView
{
    if (mainSubSelect == 100){
        self.label1.text = self.textContent;
    }
    else
    {
        self.label2.text = self.textContent;
    }
    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

Comment: As you can see I'm new to this I hope the example is readable. I reduced the problem to two view controllers rather than the Master/Detail example. My problem is still haw to keep the text in each field when another selection is made.

Comment: Edit your question with the above code, dont comment it. ;) id love to help but I dont get what you are trying to say. Rather draw a hierarchy or photoshop us something to explain better..